# Time Complexity of permutation function

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Given a collection of distinct numbers, return all possible permutations.

> For example, [1,2,3] have the following permutations:
>    [   [1,2,3],  [1,3,2],   [2,1,3],   [2,3,1],   [3,1,2],   [3,2,1] ]

My Iterative Solution is :

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new ArrayList<>());
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(List<Integer> a: result)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<=a.size();j++)
                {
                    a.add(j,nums[i]);
                    List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<>(a);
                    temp.add(current);
                    a.remove(j);
                }
            }
            result = new ArrayList<>(temp);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My Recursive Solution is:

```
public List<List<Integer>> permuteRec(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) {
            return result;
        }
        makePermutations(nums, result, 0);
        return result;
    }


void makePermutations(int[] nums, List<List<Integer>> result, int start) {
    if (start >= nums.length) {
        List<Integer> temp = convertArrayToList(nums);
        result.add(temp);
    }
    for (int i = start; i < nums.length; i++) {
        swap(nums, start, i);
        makePermutations(nums, result, start + 1);
        swap(nums, start, i);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Integer> convertArrayToList(int[] num) {
        ArrayList<Integer> item = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int h = 0; h < num.length; h++) {
            item.add(num[h]);
        }
        return item;
    }
```

According to me the time complexity(big-Oh) of my iterative solution is: n * n(n+1)/2~ O(n^3)
I am not able to figure out the time complexity of my recursive solution.
Can anyone explain complexity of both?

Comment: The number of permutations for n elements is n!, so an algorithm to produce all n! permutations would have time complexity O(n!).

Comment: for both recursion and iteration?

Comment: @OJASJUNEJA yes. It is the best conceivable runtime for this problem. Imagine if you have a magic generator that just spits out a permutation every 1 second. You would still need to wait `n!` seconds for this generator to finish because there are `n!` permutations.

Comment: The method doesn't matter. For n sufficiently greater than k, then n! > k^n, so the time complexity is O(n!). One of the few expressions greater than n! is a [double exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function), like n^(n^n).

Comment: The complexity is `O(n!) == O(n**(n + 1/2)*exp(-n))` see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The recursive solution has a complexity of `O(n!)` as it is governed by the equation: `T(n) = n * T(n-1) + O(1)`.

The iterative solution has three nested loops and hence has a complexity of `O(n^3)`.

However, the iterative solution will not produce correct permutations for any number apart from `3`.

For `n = 3`, you can see that `n * (n - 1) * (n-2) = n!`. The LHS is `O(n^3)` (or rather `O(n^n)` since `n=3` here) and the RHS is `O(n!)`.

For larger values of the size of the list, say `n`, you could have `n` nested loops and that will provide valid permutations. The complexity in that case will be `O(n^n)`, and that is much larger than `O(n!)`, or rather, `n! < n^n`. There is a rather nice relation called [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) which explains this relation.

Comment: The recurrence relation is `T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(n)`. And the iterative solution works correctly.

Comment: @MoB. the iterative solution works only for permutations of size 3. For other sizes the op will need another nested loop and is hence not a generic solution.

Comment: Why do you think that? It works perfectly fine. Try it here: https://jdoodle.com/ia/6lW

Comment: And why should the complexity of three nested loops be `O(n^3)`? It may sometimes be, or it may not (as in this case).

Comment: is this answer showing the correct recurrence relation? Not sure where O(1) belongs from the answers function: T(n) = n * T(n-1) + O(1)

Answer (score 7):

It's the *output* (which is huge) matters in this problem, not the routine's implementation. For `n` distinct items, there are `n!` permutations to be returned as the answer, and thus we have at least `O(n!)` complexity.

With a help of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

```
 O(n!) = O(n^(1/2+n)/exp(n)) = O(sqrt(n) * (n/e)^n)
```

we can easily see, that `O(n!) > O(n^c)` for *any* constant `c`, that's why it doesn't matter if the implementation itself adds another `O(n^3)` since

```
 O(n!) + O(n^3) = O(n!)
```

Answer (score 4):

In terms of number of times the method `makePermutations` is called, the exact time complexity would be:

```
O( 1 + n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... )
```

For n = 3:

```
O( 1 + 3 + (3*2) + (3*2*1) ) = O(16)
```

This means, for n = 3, the method `makePermutations` will be called 16 times.

Answer (score 0):

And I think the space complexity for an optimal permutations function would be O(n * n!) because there are n! total arrays to return, and each of those arrays is of size n.